# How to properly build dynamic WHERE clause conditions with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to be able to dynamically build JOOQ "WHERE" close, using a list of String element, where each element represents a single filer:

```java
List<String> filerList = new ArrayList<>();
    filerList.add("column1=Y");
    filerList.add("column2=Z");
```

The desired end-result should look like this:

```java
  String sql =
    DSL.select(flds)
            .from(table(tableName))
            .where(conditions)
            .getSQL();
```

I was hoping to be able to cast my filterList into Condition:

```java
    Collection<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition>();
    conditions.add((Condition) filerList);
```

But this cast fails.

What is the proper syntax to turn such a filter list into a Condition for JOOQ's WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways in jOOQ to write the kind of [dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/) that you're trying to write. In your particular case, the [`where(Collection<? extends Condition>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectWhereStep.html#where-java.util.Collection-) method is the most suitable. And again, you have several options:

#### Write ["plain SQL"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) conditions

You seem to work around using jOOQ's more type safe APIs, or even the code generator, so the appropriate way to construct your `filterList` is this:

```
List<Condition> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
filterList.add(condition("column1=Y"));
filterList.add(condition("column2=Z"));
```

The below static import is assumed to be present:

```
 import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### Create actual field references

You've created a table reference using [`DSL.table(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-java.lang.String-), so why not also create column references using [`DSL.field(String, Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), for instance?

```
List<Condition> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
filterList.add(field("column1", String.class).eq(y));
filterList.add(field("column2", Integer.class).eq(z));
```

#### Using the code generator

Of course, this would be even more powerful and simple, if you would be using the code generator.

#### Why your cast didn't work

You obviously cannot cast a `List<String>` to a `Condition`. Those types are completely unrelated and the Java compiler cannot "guess" that what you really meant was one of the above type conversions.